# Oracle Statspack Report Details on LOB listed with High Physical Read

Tags: sql, oracle

My Statspack Report shows taht around 90% of physical reads to the DB is because of a LOB.

I have given my statspack report snippet below.

```
Segments by Physical Reads  DB/Inst: PMDS2/pMDS2  Snaps: 12184-12191
-> End Segment Physical Reads Threshold:      1000

                                       Subobject    Obj.      Physical   Pct
Owner      Tablespace Object Name          Name         Type         Reads Total
---------- ---------- -------------------- ------------ ----- ------------ -----
MDSSYS     MDSDATA    SYS_LOB0000064003C00              LOB        465,135  89.0
```

How do i know more details about this LOB? How to find what exactly is the table/column holding this LOB and why it is using lot of Physical reads?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query to get information about this specific LOB:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
  FROM dba_lobs
 WHERE segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000064003C00';
```

As for the physical reads, in Oracle by default every LOB access, be it read or write, is a physical I/O a direct read from disk or a direct write to disk. You can control whether the LOB contents are cached or not with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY LOB (column_name) ( CACHE );
```

But be careful if you have big sized LOBs, the memory usage may increase dramatically!